# Fetching the pattern matched value from text file in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have a text file which has a single line of text containing 1 of the strings:

```
--Result=PASS:Passed
--Result=FAIL:Failed
```

Am trying to fetch the value PASS or FAIL using the pattern matching concept in VBScript but till now have been able to just match the string and retrieve the entire line. Please find below the code that am using:

```
Dim oRE, oMatches
Set oRE = New RegExp
oRE.Pattern = "--Result=(PASS|FAIL).*"
Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\tmp\resultfile.txt",1)
Dim strline
do while not objFileToRead.AtEndOfStream 
strline = objFileToRead.ReadLine()
Set oMatches = oRE.Execute(strline)
For Each oMatch in oMatches
result = oMatch.Value
Next
```

The result that I get now is the entire matching line. Is it possible to fetch just the PASS or FAIL substring from the text file instead of the entire line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Match` is always the entire string that matched the pattern, you are looking for the 'Groups', which you get in vbscript through `SubMatches`.

```
if oMatches.Count > 0 then
    result = oMatches(0).SubMatches(0)
end if
```

If you use multiple braces in the pattern, you can find these here through `.SubMatches(1)` etc.

Btw. your pattern does not have to match the entire input string (you don't use anchors `^$` anyway), you could just use `(PASS|FAIL)` as pattern, or maybe `=(PASS|FAIL):`.